# How to show reset button in a view only when filter is applied?

Tags: 7, views

I have created a view with four exposed filters. In exposed form settings, I added a reset link and used auto submit option. Filter and reset works fine without error, but I want to show the reset button only when the filter is applied. If no filter is applied, there should not be reset button.

I have searched, but I didn't find any solution.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hook_form_alter()` can also do this

```
function module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'Your_form_id") {
    if (!$form_state['view']->exposed_input) {
      unset($form['reset']);
    }
  }
}
```

You will have some other value for ['view']->exposed_input. Use dpm(0 to get the exposed_input value. ['view']->exposed_input returns nothing if filter is not applied. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this either using custom module[hook] or jQuery.

**Using jQuery**

1. Hide **Reset** button using CSS `display:none`.
2. Now in jQuery, on page load, check for URL containing **Query String.**

> **Example:** [view-URL]/?type=page.

3. If URL contains any **Query String**, then make **Reset** button visible.

Comment: How can do it using form alter @Nikhil Banait

Comment: Sorry, I am not the right person to explain you Custom thing :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Vamsi!
I a bit fix your code.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Show reset button in a view only when filter is applied.
  if (isset($form['reset']) && empty($form_state['view']->exposed_input)) {
    unset($form['reset']);
  }
}
```